# How to find maximum number in a 2d python list

Tags: python, list, 2d, max

I have a list in python as

```
my_list = [2,4,6,[5,10,3]]
```

How can I find the maximum number (i.e the program should return the max as 10)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flatten your list, and *then* you can use the `max()` builtin function:

```
l = [2,4,6,[5,10,3]]


def flatten(seq):
  for el in seq:
    if isinstance(el, list):
      yield from flatten(el)
    else:
      yield el

print(max(flatten(l))) # 10
```

Comment: Thank you!:) @leaf

Comment: Personally I prefer flattening the 2d list using list comprehension like so `[i for lst in l for i in lst]`

Answer (score 3):

Could be shorter/better but one way:

```
my_list = [2,4,6,[5,10,3]]
print(max(max(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x for x in my_list))
```

Comment: If you want to support only one level of flattening, you can use `max(max(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x for x in a)`, which would be easier than your expression.

Comment: Oh yes. Would it be proper practice to edit this in?

Comment: Thanks. Newly active here. So, don't know the right etiquette in many situations.

Answer (score 1):

For finding the max value, iterating twice looks extra overhead to me. Firstly, for flattening the list and then again to find the max value. Here is the example to create a recursive function to return you the max value of the nested list in a single iteration as:

```
# The good thing is, you need not to worry about the level of depth
# of the nested list, you can use it on any level of nested list

def get_max(my_list):
    m = None
    for item in my_list:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            item = get_max(item)
        if not m or m < item:
            m = item
    return m
```

Sample run:

```
>>> my_list = [2,4,6,[5,10,3]]
>>> get_max(my_list)
10
```